# Understanding max.in.flight.requests.per.connection in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Reding the [official docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_max.in.flight.requests.per.connection) about the following producer property `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`. It says:

> The maximum number of unacknowledged requests the client will send on a single connection before blocking. Note that if this config is set to be greater than 1 and enable.idempotence is set to false, there is a risk of message re-ordering after a failed send due to retries (i.e., if retries are enabled). Additionally, enabling idempotence requires this config value to be less than or equal to 5. If conflicting configurations are set and idempotence is not explicitly enabled, idempotence is disabled.

What do they mean by "unacknowledged requests the client will send"? Do they mean retry requests where there's no acks returned from the broker? And how does this effect message ordering?

Can you elaborate on what this property does?

Comment: Yes - it's requests with no ack